How to go to the modified line when using the version history in word online?
I'm using word online. At the top right corner there is a CATCH UP button.
From there I can click on VERSION HISTORY. This shows me a pane with modified date and modified by. When I click on this the document opens up but I need to read through the document to see what change was made to identify the changed line.
Is there a straight forward way that can take me to the changed line?
